# Running QGIS Plugins in Python console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-python-console

I usually use Python console in QGIS to run frequently used processing algorithms.

This time, I wish to use one of the QGIS plugins (plugin named QNEAT3) and I have downloaded it. I am able to use it with the GUI provided. However, I wish to use the Python console to run the tasks using the QNEAT3 plugin.

Is there a way to do it? I did go through the PyQGIS cookbook. Although I found examples on how to create a plugin and also how to run native processing algorithms using Python console, unfortunately, I couldn't find anything to my question.

Comment: Python console with standalone QGIS or Python console in QGIS?

Comment: Right now I am looking to access the plugin from Python console in QGIS. Is the process to access the plugin using standalone Python console different?

Comment: `from <plugin>.<file> import <class>` -> `from QNEAT3.algs.IsoAreaAsContoursFromLayer import IsoAreaAsContoursFromLayer`

Comment: You can import the class, as Tara suggested, but you'll have to be lucky that the plugin provides a method that does what you want. Often there are dependencies from the GUI or missing parameters and the like.